# Persisting Joda Date Time in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jodatime

I've a joda datetime field that I'm trying to persist into mysql using hiberante.

```
@Column  @Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentLocalDateTime")
private DateTime created;
```

This is the property and its annotation.

Here's my gradle dependency

```
compile ('org.jadira.usertype:usertype.core:6.0.1.GA')
```

I get this huge exception and can't seem to find a way around. Any help?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/ftb/auth/configs/DataConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1078) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ftb.auth.BouncerApplication.main(BouncerApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionFactoryImplementor.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.integrate(AbstractUserTypeHibernateIntegrator.java:192) ~[usertype.spi-6.0.1.GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:280) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

When I downgrade the Jadira, to match Hibernate 5.2 this is what I get,another huge stack trace.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:726) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:713) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ftb.auth.BouncerApplication.main(BouncerApplication.java:9) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:526) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:504) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:292) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.save(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.ftb.auth.init.DatabaseLoader.run(DatabaseLoader.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:723) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.joda.time.DateTime cannot be cast to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime
    at org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.columnmapper.TimestampColumnLocalDateTimeMapper.toNonNullValue(TimestampColumnLocalDateTimeMapper.java:29) ~[usertype.core-5.0.0.GA.jar:na]
    at org.jadira.usertype.spi.shared.AbstractSingleColumnUserType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnUserType.java:100) ~[usertype.spi-5.0.0.GA.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.type.CustomType.nullSafeSet(CustomType.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2661) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2946) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3449) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:89) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:582) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:456) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:337) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1282) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:465) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2963) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2339) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:485) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$100(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:231) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
```

For latest Java 17 how I can update this code so that I can remove `jadira` dependency?

Comment: @PeterPenzov You shouldn't edit someone else's question to add another question. You should have created your own.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I did a mistake. Please disregard.

Answer (score 3):

There are incompatible versions of Jadira and Hibernate.
Since you're using `Hibernate 5.0.12`, you should try `Jadira Usertype 5.0.0.GA`.

According to [release notes](http://jadira.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a6.0.1.GA):

- Jadira 6.0.0.GA (and 6.0.1.GA) is compatible with Hibernate 5.2
- Jadira 5.0.0.GA is compatible with Hibernate 5

Comment: I've added the exception that I'm getting when I downgrade the Jadira version.

Comment: `org.joda.time.DateTime cannot be cast to org.joda.time.LocalDateTime` means that you should use another type in annotation -`@Type(type="org.jadira.usertype.dateandtime.joda.PersistentDateTime")` , not `PersistentLocalDateTime`.

Comment: For latest Java 17 how I can update this code so that I can remove jadira dependency?

Comment: does org.joda.time.DateTime extends localDateTime ? i never used to dependency before i am just analyzing what's happening , so if   org.joda.time.DateTime extends localDateTime , it would be stored correctly if the date is correct and the same manner as a local date time .